# При нажатии на Label можно выбрать фотографию, которую туда загрузить

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qt-designer

Есть ли возможность при нажатии на пустое место где предусмотрен `label` открывался проводник и можно было выбрать фото для дальнейшей работы?

На данный момент реализовано это через `menuBar`, но хотелось бы от него избавится.

**Main.py**

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QDialog, QMainWindow, QMessageBox)
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PySide6.QtCore import *
from PySide6.QtGui import *
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *

from ui import Ui_MainWindow


class Window(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.ui2 = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui2.setupUi(self)

        mainMenu = self.menuBar()
        file = mainMenu.addMenu("Файл")   
        photo = QAction("Вставить фото", self)
        file.addAction(photo)
        photo.triggered.connect(self.getImage)

        self.selection = QRubberBand(QRubberBand.Rectangle, self) 
    
    def getImage(self):
        filename, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self, 
            "Выберите изображение", 
            "",
            "All Files(*.*);;PNG(*.png);;JPEG(*.jpg *.jpeg)"
        )
        if not filename:
            return
        self.ui2.label.setPixmap(QPixmap(u"{}".format(filename)))
        self.selection.hide()  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**ui.py**

```
from PySide6.QtCore import *
from PySide6.QtGui import *
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        if not MainWindow.objectName():
            MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(502, 499)
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.label = QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setObjectName(u"label")
        self.label.setGeometry(QRect(20, 20, 361, 431))
        self.label.setTextFormat(Qt.MarkdownText)
        self.label.setScaledContents(True)
        self.label.setStyleSheet('border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; border-color: black;')
        self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeading|Qt.AlignLeft|Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.label.setMargin(-3)
        self.label.setOpenExternalLinks(False)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setObjectName(u"menubar")
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 502, 22))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"MainWindow", None))
        self.label.setText("")
    # retranslateUi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо создать класс, который наследуется от `QLabel`. Создать в нем сигнал и переопределить метод `mousePressEvent`. Далее вы встраиваете этот класс в форму Qt Designer.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *

#from ui import Ui_MainWindow
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        if not MainWindow.objectName():
            MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(502, 499)
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.label = Label(self.centralwidget)                       # - QLabel, + Label   !!!
        self.label.setObjectName(u"label")
        self.label.setGeometry(QRect(20, 20, 361, 431))
        self.label.setTextFormat(Qt.MarkdownText)
        self.label.setScaledContents(True)
        self.label.setStyleSheet('border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; border-color: black;')
        self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeading|Qt.AlignLeft|Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.label.setMargin(-3)
        self.label.setOpenExternalLinks(False)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setObjectName(u"menubar")
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 502, 22))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"MainWindow", None))
        self.label.setText("")

        
class Label(QLabel):
    clicked = pyqtSignal()                                             # +++
    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.clicked.emit()                                            # +++
        

class Window(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
#?        self.setupUi(self)
        self.ui2 = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui2.setupUi(self)

        mainMenu = self.menuBar()
        file = mainMenu.addMenu("Файл")   
        photo = QAction("Вставить фото", self)
        file.addAction(photo)
        photo.triggered.connect(self.getImage)
#?        self.selection = QRubberBand(QRubberBand.Rectangle, self) 

        self.ui2.label.clicked.connect(self.getImage)                  # +++

    
    def getImage(self):
        filename, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self, 
            "Выберите изображение", 
            "",
            "All Files(*.*);;PNG(*.png);;JPEG(*.jpg *.jpeg)"
        )
        if not filename:
            return
        self.ui2.label.setPixmap(QPixmap(u"{}".format(filename)))
#?        self.selection.hide()  


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]